# Added CPUs with VBoxManage don't show up in HTOP

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

Following this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/815057/virtualbox-increase-cpu-cores-script-wise) I changed the numbers of CPUs on my guest.

I used the following commands

```
 # VM is shutdown
 VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 12" --cpus 2
 VBoxHeadless --startvm "Ubuntu 12"
```

Now, I wait for the guest to power on, SSH in and check `htop`, which shows me there's still only one CPU. What is going wrong? I assume the CPUs haven't actually been added, or haven't been initialized correctly since it's not showing up in `htop`

[image]

Content of `/proc/cpuinfo/`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2683 v3 @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x19
cpu MHz     : 0.000
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse ss$bogomips    : 4526.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Are you sure htop isn't just showing one combined line? What's in `/sys/bus/cpu/devices/` or `/sys/devices/system/cpu/`? Any directories like `cpu0`, `cpu1`, etc? Or what's `lscpu` say, anything like "CPU(s): 2" or "Core(s) per socket: 2" and one or more sockets?

Comment: Or `top` then press `1`, or what's in `/proc/cpuinfo`? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218074/how-to-know-number-of-cores-of-a-system-in-linux

Comment: @Xen2050 Each only shows one cpu. There's on directory in `/sys/bus/cpu/devices/. `top` shows only one cpu after I press `1`. And I added the content of `/proc/cpuinfo/` in an edit.